# Body's initial velocity is too fast when created after minimax algo

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I don't know if my question is right but I cannot address the real problem.
I am dropping connect 4 game chips under gravity but when I apply minimax with a depth of 3, it starts with great velocity.
My code for render loop is:

```
private List<List<Chip>> chips;

public void render(float delta){
    world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    game.batch.begin();

    for(List<Chip> chipList: chips){
        for(Chip chip: chipList) {
            chip.setPosition(chip.getBody().getPosition().x-chip.getRadius(), chip.getBody().getPosition().y-chip.getRadius());
            chip.draw(game.batch);
        }
    }

    if(chipready){
        chip.createBody();
        chips.get(yellowIndex).add(chip);
        chip.draw(game.batch);
        chipready = false;
    }

    game.batch.end();
}
```

Here Chip is a subclass of `Sprite`.

Code for my contact listener:

```
    world.setContactListener(listener = new ContactListener() {
        @Override
        public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
            Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
            Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();
            if (fixA.getUserData() == "chip" && fixB.getUserData() == "floor" || (fixA.getUserData() == "floor" && fixB.getUserData() == "chip"){
                yellowIndex = BestMove.minimaxutil( board, AI_PIECE);
                chip = new Chip(world, x, y, radius);
                chipready = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like we have enough code here to be able to help you yet. You mention velocity and minimax, but we don't see any code related to velocity or minimax here. Please edit your question so that it contains a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example: all the code/steps that a reader would need to reproduce the problem in a new, empty project.

Comment: Since the whole code for minimax is very big, it's the best I can put here.

Comment: If it's not enough to reproduce the problem, then this question will be closed. Please verify that you can reproduce the problem using *only* what you've documented in your question. You may need to make a stripped down version of your project that demonstrates this problem in isolation, without any of the other stuff your game does currently.